# Changing the quality of icons on leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I'm creating a map with the leaflet package for R but I feel a bit disappointed with the quality of the icons and would like to improve it.
I'm using free png icons from [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/).
The pngs look just fine but when plotted, they lose their "smoothness" and look low quality.

```
library('leaflet')
library('sf')



points = data.frame(p = seq(15, 75, 15), 
                     long = c(-85, -80, -78, -75, -82), 
                     lat = c(34, 36, 37, 38, 35)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('long', 'lat'), crs = 4326)

fork_icon = makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "https://static.thenounproject.com/png/2036274-200.png", 
  iconWidth = 20, iconHeight = 20)

circle_icon = makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1904581-200.png", 
  iconWidth = 15, iconHeight = 15)

basemap = leaflet(points[c(1,4),],options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.EPSG4326"))) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(icon = fork_icon) %>%
  addMarkers(data = points[c(2,3),], icon = circle_icon)
```

That looks like:

[image]

Now if I don't "compress" the icons with the `makeIcon` options `iconWidth` and `iconHeight`, they look nice and smooth again.

[image]

Any leads on how to keep the icons smooth while keeping them in a convenient size?

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce a png with such delicate features to 15px there's not much you can do. I would suggest trying to use SVG images. This can be done using `divIcon`, like in this example: https://codepen.io/localhorst/pen/BJxzGW

*Disclaimer:
The codepen is not my code, credit goes to [this guy](https://marcus-obst.de/#content) and I haven't tested it myself.